# Unable to curl from Windows 10 Powershell with X-API-KEY

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, httprequest

I have been trying to curl from windows powershell but no luck.

```
curl -O -J -H  @{'X-Api-Key' = 'abcdefghijk'} https://my.repo.com/abc/xyz
```

I am getting the following error

```
curl : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -O -J -H  @{'X-Api-Key' = 'abcdefgh'} ht ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: It might be useful to mention that curl is an alias for the PowerShell cmdlet, `Invoke-WebRequest`, and not curl as many others might know it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Robin pointed out in his comment; `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` (see your exception details for more information!

So basically... it's not curl!

This means that the switches you are providing *might not* map as you'd expect.

First thing to mention is that whilst PowerShell allows you to use shortened parameter names, you really, **really** shouldn't use them!

- `-O` = `-OutFile` (probably not what you want...)
- `-J` = ...there is none!
- `-H` = `-Headers` (looks right for you)

I reckon that's the root cause of your issues - you need to look at the documentation for the CmdLet

```
Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest
Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Online ## this will open in browser with full details
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried without -O and -J, just with '-H' No luck. Is it something like Invoke-WebRequest doesn't accept/understand x-api-key?

Comment: Same error message? You should look at the other switches in the documentation; e.g. `-Method`